# D3's node's data

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, nodes

I have a problem with the node's data on D3.

I'm using a CSV file for my data. Suppose my CSV file has a source and a target like the following:

```
source    target
A         B
A         C 
A         D
B         D
C         E
```

and the code for creating distinct nodes is

```
var nodes = {};

links.forEach(function(link) {

    link.source = nodes[link.source] ||  
        (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source, to: link.target, countOut: 0,           
        countIn: 0});           
    link.source.countOut++;      

    link.target = nodes[link.target] || 
        (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target, countOut: 0, countIn: 0});        
    link.target.countIn++;

});
```

I made a popup when there is a click event on a node. In my popup, I want it to display the source and the target of that node. But it displays only one target node for the source node. For example, the target of source `A` is `B`. It doesn't show all the targets of source `A` which are `B`, `C`, and `D`. I want it to display all of the targets that the source has. Is it possible to do that?

Here is the code for my popup

```
// action to take on mouse click
function popNode(d) {
d3.select("#popup").remove();
popup1 = d3.select("#aside")
       .append("div")
       .attr("id", "popup");
    popup1.append("h2").text(d.name);
    popup1.append("h2").text("to: " + d.to);

    showing = true;

    d3.select("#popup").on("click", function(){
        d3.select("#popup").remove();
        showing = false;
    });
}
```

The code below is for what is d in the popup

```
var node = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("node")
    .data(force.nodes())
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .on("click", popNode)
    .on("mouseover", fade(.2))
    .on("mouseout", fade(1))
    .call(force.drag);

// add the nodes
node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 5);
```

For the whole js code

```
// get the data
d3.json("case1.csv", function(d) {

return {
      source: d.source, 
      date: d.date,
      time: d.time,
      type: d.type,
      target: d.target
    };
  }, function(error, rows) {
    console.log(rows);
    links = rows;

var nodes = {};

// Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
links.forEach(function(link) {

    link.source = nodes[link.source] ||  
        (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source, countOut: 0, countIn: 0});            
    link.source.countOut++;      

    link.target = nodes[link.target] || 
        (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target, countOut: 0, countIn: 0});        
    link.target.countIn++;

});

var width = 700,
    height = 450;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
    .links(links)
    .size([width, height])
    .linkDistance(60)
    .charge(-300)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();

var svg = d3.select("#content").append("svg")
    .attr("id", "kwai")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)     
    .attr("viewbox", "0 0 700 450")
    .attr("perserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMid")
    .call(d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 8]).on("zoom", zoom))
    .append("g");

svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "overlay")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

// build the arrow.
svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data(["end"])      // Different link/path types can be defined here
  .enter().append("svg:marker")    // This section adds in the arrows
    .attr("id", String)
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 15)
    .attr("refY", -1.5)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
  .append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

// add the links and the arrows
var path = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("path")
    .data(force.links())
  .enter().append("svg:path")
//    .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)")
    .on("click", popLink);

// define the nodes
var node = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("node")
    .data(force.nodes())
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .on("click", popNode)
    .on("mouseover", fade(.2))
    .on("mouseout", fade(1))
    .call(force.drag);

// add the nodes
node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 5);

// add the text 
node.append("text")
    .attr("x", 12)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

function zoom() {
  svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale     
+ ")");
}

var linkedByIndex = {};
links.forEach(function(d) {
    linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = 1;
});

function isConnected(a, b) {
    return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index] || linkedByIndex[b.index + "," +     
a.index] || a.index == b.index;
}

var chart = $("#kwai"),
    aspect = chart.width() / chart.height(),
    container = chart.parent();

$(window).on("resize", function() {
    var targetWidth = container.width();
    chart.attr("width", targetWidth);
    chart.attr("height", Math.round(targetWidth / aspect));
}).trigger("resize");

// add the curvy lines
    function tick() {
  path.attr("d", linkArc);

  node.attr("transform", transform);
}

function linkArc(d) {
  var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
      dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
      dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
  return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " +   
d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
}

 function transform(d) {
  return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
}

showing = false;

// action to take on mouse click
function popNode(d) {
        d3.select("#popup").remove();
        popup1 = d3.select("#aside")
                .append("div")
                .attr("id", "popup");
        popup1.append("h2").text(d.name);

        //popup1.append("h2").text("to: " + d.to);
        popup1.append("h2").text("out: " + d.countOut);
        popup1.append("h2").text("in: " + d.countIn);

        showing = true;

        d3.select("#popup").on("click", function(){
            d3.select("#popup").remove();
            showing = false;
        });
}

function popLink(d) {
        d3.select("#popup").remove();
        popup1 = d3.select("#aside")
                .append("div")
                .attr("id", "popup");
        popup1.append("h2").text(d.time);   
        showing = true;

        d3.select("#popup").on("click", function(){
            d3.select("#popup").remove();
            showing = false;
        });
}

function fade(opacity) {
    return function(d) {
        node.style("stroke-opacity", function(o) {
            thisOpacity = isConnected(d, o) ? 1 : opacity;
            this.setAttribute('fill-opacity', thisOpacity);
            return thisOpacity;
        });

        path.style("opacity", opacity).style("opacity", function(o) {
            return o.source === d || o.target === d ? 1 : opacity;
        });
    };
}

});
```

Comment: Your code supports only a single target, not a list of targets. To do that, make `link.target` an array. This will break the other code you're working with though (I'm guessing that you're using a force layout).

Comment: Yes, I'm using a force layout. I don't mind changing my codes, so is there any example that is similar to what I want or could you please guide me a little? Thank you so much =D

Comment: Wait, scrap that last comment. I see what you're trying to do now. Can you post the complete code for the popup please?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, here is the code for the popup:   Thank you.

Comment: Could you please add that as an edit to your question? Also, how is this called? In particular, what are `d` and `d.to`?

Comment: It will call the popNode function when there is a click on a node .on("click", popNode). d is the data of the node that has been clicked. d.to refers to link.target of the node that has been clicked which is the data (see the code for creating distinct node). If I change it to d.name then it would return me the node's name because name is link.source. So here is the problem, d.to has only one value or one target, but I want it to keep all of the target of the node.

Comment: Ok, can you show us the code you're using to set `.to`?

Comment: link.source = nodes[link.source] ||  
        (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source, to: link.target, countOut: 0,           
        countIn: 0});

Comment: to: link.target (from code for creating distinct nodes)

Comment: Ok, so my first instinct was actually right (see first comment). You need to make that an array.

Comment: Yes, but I just cant find a way to do that. If you cound provide me some examples, it would be helpful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It would help if you could provide a complete working example of what you have.

Comment: If you need the any other files please tell me. Thank you !

Comment: It would be great if you could assemble a working example on something like http://plnkr.co/